# extract data of one interface from another interface object which extends it

Tags: typescript

I have the below code.Is that possible to extract Dept object data from emp variable below?

```
    interface Dept{
        deptId: number;
        deptName: string;
    }


    interface Emp extends Dept{
        Id: number;
        Name: string;
    }

    let emp:Emp = {Id=1,Name='John',deptId=101,deptName='Sales'}
    console.log(emp.dept);//doesn't work
```

I can read individual properties of dept from emp object if i declare Dept type variable in Emp interface instead of extending Dept interface.

But I would like to know if there is a better way where we can just specify something like emp.dept and read entire dept object in my current code above where i extend dept interface.

Comment: Where is the `dept`in Emp Interface?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your assignment to `emp` property does not compile. Use semicolons instead

```
let emp:Emp = {Id:1,Name:'John',deptId:101,deptName:'Sales'}
```

Secondly, there is no `dept` property in your object. But you can do the following

```
console.log(emp.deptId);
```

In case you want to have `Dept` object you should use composition instead of inheritance

```
interface Emp {
        Id: number;
        Name: string;
        Dept : Dept;
}

let emp:Emp = {Id:1,Name:'John', Dept: {deptId: 101, deptName: 'Sales'}}
```

Furthermore, I think you should [prefer composition in that case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Inheriting employee from the department is a case of wrong abstraction. As a rule of thumb, you should use inheritance when there is "is-a" relation between classes. Employee is clearly not a department.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Emp` extends `Dept`, `Emp` **is** a `Dept` as far as typescript is concerned. That is, you can simply do:

```
const dept: Dept = emp;
```

The only reason to filter the properties would be when you are passing `emp` to a function that iterates over all properties, such as a remote API that takes exception to unexpected properties.

Alas, since interfaces do not survive transpilation, the runtime does not know which properties your interface contained. Therefore, you must specify the properties to copy explicitly.

One way to do this is using a destructuring assignment, either by specifying the properties you want copied:

```
const {debtId, debtName} = emp;
const dept = {deptId, debtName};
```

or by specifying those you don't want copied:

```
const {Id, Name, ...dept} = emp;
```